# Why is this two table into one table union, where showing invalid result in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have a table1 (records 3), and table2 (records 3).

- Where i have field name in both.
- Now i want to make a result from those two table
- which will show me both table records and take only one if there is duplicate.
- from that result i will do main query using like or or other logical statements
- So my expected output records will contain 5 rows not 6 rows. How do i do that?

**Example:**

```
table1:                       table2:

+-------------------------+   +--------------------------------+
| Name            | ID        | Name            | ID
+--------------------------   +---------------------------------
| A               |  1        | 1 December Name | 4
| B               |  2        | D               | 5
| 1 December Name |  3        | E               | 6


My Expected output is following which works, but does not work when i use WHERE
like to only get '1 December Name':

+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Name               | ID                
+-----------------------------------------------------
| A                  | 1 table1
| B                  | 2 table1
| 1 December Name    | 3 table2 or table1 (no unique)
| D                  | 4 table2
| E                  | 5 table2
```

**I tried this:**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    ( 
     SELECT name AS name FROM table1 
    ) 
UNION 
    ( 
     SELECT anothername AS name FROM table2 
    )
) as t
WHERE name like '%1 December Name%'
    limit 1,10
```

Output: Your SQL query has been executed successfully ( Query took 0.2798 sec )

Problem: The following query has no error but it does not find that record which contain '1 December Name'

**Follow up:** works i know now which ID it used

```
SELECT NAME, ID, STATUS FROM 
(
 (
   SELECT NAME AS name       , id, CONCAT('table1')   AS STATUS FROM table1
 )
UNION ALL
 (
   SELECT ANOTHERNAME AS name, id, CONCAT( 'table2' ) AS STATUS FROM table2
 )
) AS t

WHERE 

 t.NAME LIKE '%1 December Name%'

LIMIT 1 , 10;
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `limit 1,10` part of your query?

Comment: If you remove the WHERE clause, what results do you get?

Comment: Without WHERE clause, whole list. Without limit 1,10 also nothing.

Comment: t.name ... does not work too.

Comment: Please check that the record really exists with `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name like '%1 December Name%'` and the same for table 2.  You example code suggests to me that if it does exist, it's not identical to your search.  Maybe `1st` instead of `1`, or with a typo in `December`, etc, etc.

Comment: 100% confirmed. The column in both table has '1 December Name'

Comment: Two table on my left screen is showing and both has column value '1 December Name' no typo no 1st its `1' confirmed.

Comment: If you remove the WHERE clause, do you see '1 December Name' once or twice?

Comment: `LIMIT 1,10` means `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1`. Try using `LIMIT 0,10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get something similar to what you want:

```
select name, group_concat(id) from
(select name, 'table1' as id from table1
union all 
select name, 'table2' from table2) x
group by name
```

Output would be:

```
+------------------------------------+
| Name               | ID                
--------------------------------------
| A                  | table1
| B                  | table1
| 1 December Name    | table1,table2
| D                  | table2
| E                  | table2
```

`UNION ALL` is the right choice (not `UNION`), because it does *not* remove duplicates, and preserves row order

Comment: @Google: Are you sure? Bohemian's SQL looks sound to me. (`UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` would be more efficient in this case.).

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: yes i am just testing on my left screen what ever we have in this page. And all just failed to find only 1 record which contain "1 December Name".

Comment: @Google Erwin is right: It should be `UNION ALL`. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
(SELECT `name` FROM table1 )
UNION (SELECT `name` FROM table2);